# How do we create a scratch org with sandbox environment?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to achieve creation of a scratch org in the 30 days trail version of Dev hub account as shown below from Dream force 2017 Developer Keynote.

[image: This pic is from Developer Keynote in Dream force 2017].

I got the below error!

[image: I am stuck with this error!].

Have anyone tried to configure the scratch org with sourceorg?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature being discussed in the video is not generally available for all. It is related to Org Shape for Scratch Org. It is currently in Pilot and only available for people taking part in the pilot program. So you won't be able to use it until it is GA.

Comment: just checking in is this available now, where can i check this? if you can provide me a link that will be helpful.

Comment: I think found it, just incase any one want to follow this.https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm

Comment: Going into Beta, open to all starting in Winter '21 as per [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/319383/55891)