# Salesforce DX scratch Org

Tags: scratch-org

during the dreamforce17 i notice that we can create a copy of our production as a scratch org

> {
>       "orgName": "XXXXXXXXXXx",
>       "edition": "Enterprise",
>       "features": "MultiCurrency;AuthorApex;PersonAccounts",
>       "country": "NL",
>       "language": "en-EN",
>      "sourceOrg": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>       "orgPreferences": {
>           "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled"]
>       }
>   }

but when i try it i get this error :

> ERROR:  No such column 'SourceOrg' on sobject of type ScratchOrgInfo.

Has somebody an idea?

Comment: Can you link to the resource where this was discussed? Was this in a presentation?

Comment: it was in developer keynote 2017 presented by wade wegner https://youtu.be/7AHpJP39Kv8?t=767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is currently in Pilot and only available for people taking part in the pilot program
[answred here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/198432/how-do-we-create-a-scratch-org-with-sandbox-environment/198435#198435)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that JSON you provided is a scratch org definition file, you cannot specify "sourceOrg" property. Properties available are:

1. orgName
2. country
3. username
4. adminEmail
5. edition
6. description
7. hasSampleData
8. language
9. features
10. orgPreferences

Values of these are specified here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should check "Enable Org Shape for Scratch Orgs" toggle to true in both Source and Dev Hub orgs and provide Dev Hub org's Id in Org Shape setup in source org