# Salesforce DX - How enable org shape?

Tags: salesforcedx

I did not find any content relate to how enable a org so I can create an org shape.

I am getting the following error when I run the command `sfdx force:org:shape:create`:

`ERROR:  The org needs to be enabled for org shape before one can be created.`

Neither my DevHub trial org or my scratch org has the option to enable it or even anything related with 'shape' under the Setup Menu.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Org Shape feature is in pilot status as of [Winter 18](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm).

It is not yet generally available and cannot be enabled on "off-the-shelf" Dev Hubs. My understanding is that the feature is only enabled in orgs that are created as part of the org shape pilot.

Comment: thanks for bringing me the light, the information is here: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_pilot_shape.htm but I have not interpreted it properly

Comment: Furthermore, this video might be helpful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDBb0RDqY2A

Answer (score 5):

It has entered Beta as of Winter 21. Still not production, but it should be available to all

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_scratch_orgs_shape.htm

Answer (score 0):

There was a sign up form (closed as of April 2019) for a pilot to be able to use org shapes. As of September 2019, this is the 2nd year the pilot is running. This should be widely released soon...hopefully.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfJDo3yrrOQVuBE4Op_F5Udl9XMSNdk0e7_sXjhtXYGcqjU6w/viewform